# Validator Reward curve tweaking without runtime upgrade

Tags: runtime, rewards

I am facing with the following issue:
There might be a future need of changing the configuration for the reward curve for validator. I believe this is possible only be changing the linear piece wise construct in the runtime via the appropriate macro. This implies that a runtime upgrade is necessary for having the configuration active on the network.

Question: Is there a way to achieve a similar end result without the need of a runtime upgrade?